# Changing network interface names on RedHat

Tags: redhat, interface, name

I have a DELL server running RedHat EL 6.3 with two 1G network interfaces, and two 10G network interfaces.

Following [this note](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/sect-Consistent_Network_Device_Naming-Notes.html), I have successfully renamed the two 1G network interfaces that used to be called `em1` and `em2`. However, I cannot rename the 10G network interfaces using this method. (Those are called `p4p1` and `p4p2`, and do not start with `em`.)

How can I rename the network interface name of my 10G network interfaces on RedHat EL 6.3?

Comment: If you're just renaming them back to the old `eth*` names, you're just wasting your time and setting yourself up for trouble in the future. [The consistent naming feature makes your job easier](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/ConsistentNetworkDeviceNaming); it's strongly recommended to use them.

Comment: I'm renaming them back to `eth*` names because I have no choice. A certain piece of software (which I have no control over) imposes the `eth*` names.

Comment: Oh, what an unholy mess some of those old legacy software...

Comment: Beware that [recent udev (really systemd) versions no longer support assigning stable `eth*` names to interfaces](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=53837) (although this obviously won't affect RHEL6, the new code may turn up in RHEL7). A workaround I can think of is using numbers which are not less than the total number of interfaces in the system (e.g., if you definitely do not expect more than 4 `eth*` interfaces, you can assign stable names starting with `eth4`, so that they will not overlap with names automatically assigned by the kernel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the section of the appendix you linked to states, it's strongly recommended to enable or disable the consistent network device naming feature at install time; doing so after installation is messy and not guaranteed to work, as you've discovered.

To do this, *install* the system passing `biosdevname=0` on the boot command line when booting the installation media, *and* add the same parameter to the grub boot command line.

Since you've just installed the system anyway, this shouldn't be too big of a headache...

Answer (score 1):

I know that my answer is really late, but this can help other people searching for this information, so here it goes:

It is better to give these 2 options as kernel parameters:

```
biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0
```

To add this to the boot you can do:

```
/sbin/grubby --update-kernel=`/sbin/grubby --default-kernel` --args="biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0 "
```

Or modify the **/etc/default/grub** and add **biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0"" to the **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX** and regenerate grub configuration:

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Example of the */etc/default/grub* entry:

```
# cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=rhel_7/swap rd.luks.uuid=luks-cc387312-6da6-469a-8e49-b40cd58ad67a crashkernel=auto  vconsole.keymap=us vconsole.font=latarcyrheb-sun16 rd.lvm.lv=rhel_7/root rhgb quiet net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
```